# How to use s3 input plugin in Logstash without providing s3 access credentials?

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-s3, logstash, elastic-stack, credentials

I am attempting to ingest data from an s3 bucket (openalex) that is publicly available (https://openalex.s3.amazonaws.com/browse.html) and load it into ElasticSearch directly. The bucket is publicly accessible, and you can download the files in it without any credentials as well.

When using the aws command line, you can simply use the --no-sign-request flag to specify that no credentials will be used. However, when I attempt to ingest data from s3 using logstash, it asks me for credentials. I have tried removing the credential fields, as well as trying dummy credentials, but neither approach works, and it fails giving the following error:

> logstash_1  |   Error: unable to sign request without credentials set
>
> logstash_1  |   Exception: Aws::Errors::MissingCredentialsError

My logstash config file is as follows:

```
input {
  s3 {
    bucket => "openalex"
    region => "us-east-1"
    access_key_id => "AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE" #Dummies I have tried, and tried removing these as well
    secret_access_key => "wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY" #dummy
    prefix => "/data/works/updated_date=2024-01-05/"
    codec => "json_lines"
  }
}

filter {
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://es01:9200"]
    index => "openalex-works-2024-01-05"
    user => "<hidden>"
    password => "<hidden>"
  }
}
```

Would love to know of any solutions you might have.